# How to debug unexpected behaviour in useEffect in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const FelixContext = createContext(undefined);

const FelixContextProvider = (props) => {

  const [ targets, setTargets ] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(targets);
  }, [targets])

  const addTarget = (target) => {
    let t = targets;
    t.push(target);
    console.log(t);
    setTargets(t);
  }

  return(
    <FelixContext.Provider value={{targets, setTargets, addTarget}}>
      {props.children}
    </FelixContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { FelixContext };
export default FelixContextProvider;
```

Why is useEffect not working here after I update the targets state variable with a value? When I console.log t variable it's giving the value as I want but the same is not reflecting in useEffect as it's not getting executed.

Comment: try this 

const addTarget = (target) => {
  setTargets([...targets, target]);
}

const addTarget = (target) => {
  setTargets(targets.concat(target));
}

Comment: Remember that "it's not working" is not a problem description. [Be detailed in your post](/help/how-to-ask): please [edit] your post to talk about what you needed to do, show the code you wrote to do that, talk about what you expected it to do but what it's doing instead, and what you've already done/(re)searched to solve the problem before you resorted to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Perhaps because you're not changing `targets` - you're updating the contents of the array but the reference never changes. Instead of mutating the array, you create a new one like `[...targets, target]`;

Answer (score 1):

The value of `targets` is never changed, only the contents inside of the array are changing.

If you change your `addTarget` to actually update the contents in the state your `useEffect` will trigger.

```
const addTarget = (target) => {
  setTargets([...targets, target]);
}
```